# TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, tablelayoutpanel

does the TableLayoutPanel exist in VS 2005?

Comment: Too narrow and simple and not really a programming question.  SO shouldn't be flooded with questions about what individual classes are included in which versions of programming tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it first appeared in .NET 2.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TableLayoutPanel is a standard component of the .NET 2.0, thus it is usable from VS2k5.